# Kendo Angular's Auto complete showing object in results

Tags: javascript, angularjs, autocomplete, kendo-ui

I am trying to use kendo angular's auto complete widget using server filtering. After the service call the popup shows [object Object] and the number of these is equal to the results returned from the server. So could you please have a look at my code and point me to the mistake I am doing.

Here is my code:

```
var oThis = this;
var uiQueryConfig = this.seUIConfigsCacheService.GetItem('OpportunityDashboard');

var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
serverFiltering: true,
serverPaging: true,
pageSize: 20,
transport: {
   read: function (options) {
           oThis.getDataFromServer(options, uiQueryConfig, false, options.data.filter.filters[0].value);
         }
   }
});

$scope.dataSource = dataSource;
```

Here is the definition of getDataFromServer:

```
getDataFromServer(options: any, uiConfig: Model.UIConfig, recordsCountNeeded: boolean, searchText?: string): void {

var searchParam = new Model.SearchParamsCM();
searchParam.PageIndex = options.data.page;
searchParam.PageSize = options.data.pageSize;
searchParam.SearchText = searchText;

var oThis = this;

this._seHttpService.GetWithParms('/spa/api/genericrequest', searchParam)
    .then(function (result) {
        var datum = oThis.createJSONFromResults(result.data, uiConfig);

        if (recordsCountNeeded) //grid
            options.success(datum);
        else //auto complete
            options.success(datum.data);
        },
        function (result) {
            options.error(result);
    });
 }
```

The code is in typescript.

This is in template:

```
<input id="name" kendo-auto-complete k-min-length="3" k-data-text-field="name" k-ignore-case="true" k-data-source="dataSource" ng-model="searchText" />
```

I tried to debug the options.success function and found out that the parameter value there has a lot of other information including the whole object returned from the server instead of the one I am passing it i.e. datum.data.

Thanks in anticipation!

EDIT:
Ok I have sorted it out. actually there were two issues, first that the variable name in k-data-text-field should be in single quotes i.e. k-data-text-field="'name'". Second the variable name is case sensitive so it should have been k-data-text-field="'Name'"

Comment: Could you please look at the data in the datasource ? dataSource._data. Use the chrome console to see the data structure. Do your data objects in there have a property called name ? Is it a string ?

Comment: I am not sure how will I check the dataSource._data because the service is called inside transport's read property of dataSource. Inside this function datasource has not been built so where do I check it?

Comment: ok I have checked the datasource inside select event of autocomplete. yes my data is there which is a collection of objects and there is a property called Name in it.

Comment: you should close the question with a proper answer, not a comment, not an edit. thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I have sorted it out. actually there were two issues, first that the variable name in k-data-text-field should be in single quotes i.e. `k-data-text-field="'name'"`. Second the variable name is case sensitive so it should have been `k-data-text-field="'Name'"`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to relieve your HTML from too much attributes, you could pass k-options attribute to your kendo element like this:

```
<input id="name" kendo-auto-complete k-options="acOptions" k-data-source="dataSource" ng-model="searchText" />
```

and then define the options on your scope like this:

```
$scope.acOptions = {
   minLength: 3,
   dataTextField: 'name'
   ignoreCase: true
}
```